# the window of running the model in Anylogic doesn't show anything

Tags: model, anylogic

The bug seems simple like there's a missing plugin but I don't know it.
When I run my model the window freezes on the Anylogic logo but it works and runs normally on the Anylogic cloud.
[see the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzaN8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some students I was teaching with the Personal Learning Edition (PLE) of AnyLogic 8.7.0 had this issue with some models they created from scratch (and it was persistent when closing/reopening the model and/or AnyLogic).

The problem no longer seems to be occurring with the recently released AnyLogic 8.7.1 (though the change history doesn't mention any such bugs being fixed), so if you're using the PLE (or even if not) and were not already on version 8.7.1, I'd try upgrading in the first instance.

**EDIT**: AnyLogic 8.7.2 explicitly lists this as a bug fixed in the change history ("Engine: Fixed bug: animation window could be blank upon model start") so upgrading to 8.7.2 should definitely fix it if 8.7.1 didn't.